# Escaping Shell Command Arguments in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to fully understand the following command in Vim:

```
:exe "grep -R " . shellescape(expand("<cWORD>")) . " ."<cr>
```

I got the use of *expand* function (force the expansion of  into the actual string
before it gets passed to shellescape) and *shellescape* command itself (    from Vim help page: Escape {string} for use as a shell command argument).

What I do not understand, from help itself either, is that use of dots, one before and one after *shellescape* command.

Again, both of the dots are preceeded and followed by an empty space.
And if I use :

```
:exe "grep -R "shellescape(expand("<cWORD>"))" ."<cr>
```

which is the same command without those dots, I (apparently) get the same result.

Can anybody give a detailed explanation?

Thank you

Comment: `.` is the string concatenation operator in Vim. Most other languages use `+`. It looks like your example command is missing at least one `"` as well.

Comment: [expr6 .  expr6 .. String concatenation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:help :execute`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) already explains that.

As you can see from the `:exe[cute] {expr1} ..` syntax, it takes multiple arguments.

> Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
>     between.  To avoid the extra space use the "."
>     operator to concatenate strings into one argument.

[`:help expr-.`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-.) explains that the operator for String concatenation in Vimscript is `.` (not `+` like in many other languages; in Vimscript, this solely is for adding numbers or Lists). The empty space around it is optional, but often given for better readability.

In summary, if you need to concatenate Strings with spaces, you can either use `.` and include the space inside one of the Strings, or pass separate arguments to `:execute` and let it add the spaces implicitly, or mix both approaches within the same command (readability should be the first priority here).